# why did we use ' - ' (negative) sign before cross_val_score

Tags: python, scikit-learn

why did we use ' -cross_val_score ' instead of just cross_val_score?

```
cv_mae = -cross_val_score(lm,
                         x_train,y_train,
                         cv=10,
                         scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a convention in `scikit-learn`:

> All scorer objects follow the convention that **higher return values are better than lower return values**. Thus metrics which measure the distance between the model and the data, like `metrics.mean_squared_error`, are available as `neg_mean_squared_error` which return the negated value of the metric.

(quoted from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#the-scoring-parameter-defining-model-evaluation-rules))

Since your `cross_val_score` returns the negative MAE (see that you passed `scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error'` as a parameter), you need the negative sign to get the actual MAE.

Comment: So the "negative cancel out negative" to get a positive result, once our work of "neg_mean_absolute_error" is done ? Right?

Comment: @pratikkandalgaonkar yes, that's basically it.